# WordPress pre_get_posts causing custom menu to fail

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to target the tag template with the pre_get_posts function to add post types to the query. The code I am using seems super basic and should work no problem. However, it's not and is breaking the query and more importantly, somehow it's breaking the custom menus from being returned on that tag template only.

```
function tags_support_query($query) {
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'any');
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tags_support_query');
```

Thank you in advance for any input/advice.

Comment: When you say "breaking the query", what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Add `$query->is_main_query()` constraint to if statement like below :

```
function tags_support_query($query) {
    if( is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'any');
    }
}
```